# Place boost python extension inside package

Tags: c++, python-2.7, boost-python

I have the following boost python code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

class PyExtTest
{
public:
    std::string get_name() { return m_name; }
    void set_name(std::string const& name) { m_name = name; }

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test_ext)
{
    bp::class_<PyExtTest>("pet")
        .add_property("name", &PyExtTest::get_name, &PyExtTest::set_name)
        ;
}
```

which I compile into the the following directory hierarchy using distutils:

```
build/lib/test_ext.so
```

and then use (with `PYTHONPATH` set to `build/lib`) as so:

```
import test_ext
a = test_ext.pet
a.name = 'dog'
print a.name     # dog
```

When I configure distutils to install `test_ext` as part of package `pkg`, python can no longer find the module. I end up with the directory hierarchy:

```
build/lib/pkg
build/lib/pkg/__init__.py
build/lib/pkg/test_ext.so
```

from using a setup script like:

```
test_module = Extension('pkg.test_ext'
                        , define_macros = module_macros
                        , extra_compile_args = module_compiler_flags
                        , sources = ['pkg/test_ext/test.cpp']
                        , include_dirs = module_include_dirs
                        , library_dirs = module_lib_dirs
                        , libraries = module_libs)

setup (name = 'Test'
       , version = '0.1'
       , description = 'Test'
       , packages = ['pkg']
       , ext_modules = [test_module])
```

but trying to import the module:

```
import pkg.test_ext
```

results in the error:

```
ImportError: No module named test_ext
```

If I substitute a pure python module for `test_ext`, then everything works as expected.

I think I need to change the boost code in some manner to indicate that the `test_ext` extension is inside the `pkg` package, but I cannot figure out exactly how to do it.

I tried just moving `test_ext.so` to the correct location in the `build/lib` directory hierarchy to get the package layout that I wanted, but the only place it is recognized as a module is directly under `build/lib`. This is different the `.py` files, which I can import successfully from wherever I place them in the directory hierarchy.

I am using `python 2.7.6` and `boost 1.55`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As demonstrated in the Boost.Python [`Creating Packages`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/techniques.html#python.creating_packages) tutorial, there is nothing special required between importing a pure python module and a python extension module.

---

Given the following directory structure, where `src/pkg/__init__.py` is empty and `src/test_ext/test_ext.cpp` contains the Boost.Python code posted in the question:

```
.
|-- setup.py
'-- src
    |-- pkg
    |   '-- __init__.py
    '-- test_ext
        └'-- test_ext.cpp
```

With the following `setup.py` file containing paths specific to my environment:

```python
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

test_module = Extension('pkg.test_ext',
                        sources=['src/test_ext/test_ext.cpp'],
                        include_dirs=['/usr/local/include'],
                        library_dirs=['/usr/local/lib/boost'],
                        runtime_library_dirs=['/usr/local/lib/boost'],
                        libraries=['boost_python'])

setup(name='Test',
      version='0.1',
      description='Test',
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      packages=['pkg'],
      ext_modules=[test_module])
```

The `python setup.py build` command produces the following directory tree:

```
.
|-- build
¦   |-- lib.linux-i686-2.7
¦   ¦   '-- pkg
¦   ¦       |-- __init__.py
¦   ¦       '-- test_ext.so
¦   '-- temp.linux-i686-2.7
¦       '-- src
¦           '-- test_ext
¦               '-- test_ext.o
|-- setup.py
'-- src
    |-- pkg
    ¦   '-- __init__.py
    '-- test_ext
        '-- test_ext.cpp
```

The `pkg.text_ext` module can be imported by adding the `build/lib.linux-i686-2.7` directory path to the Python [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).  For example, either appending the path to:

- the [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable before starting the interpreter
- the `sys.path` list within the interpreter.

In this example, I have opted to start the interpreter from the directory that contains `build` and append `build/lib.linux-i686-2.7` to `sys.path`:

```python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('build/lib.linux-i686-2.7')
>>> import pkg.test_ext
>>> parrot = pkg.test_ext.pet()
>>> parrot
<pkg.test_ext.pet object at 0xb7439a7c>
>>> parrot.name = 'Polly'
>>> print parrot.name
Polly
```

---

If failures still occur when importing the module, then consider running python with [`-vv`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-trace-v) arguments.  This will cause python to print verbose tracing messages for each file that is checked when importing.  It may be helpful to observe where Python is searching and finding the `pkg` package, but failing to find the `test_ext` module.  For example, if I start the Python interpreter from within the `src` directory:

```python
src$ python -vv
# ... some python loading verbose tracing ...
>>> import
# ... get the verbose tracing for the imports import needs out of the way...
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import pkg.test_ext
import pkg # directory pkg
# trying pkg/__init__.i386-linux-gnu.so
# trying pkg/__init__.so
# trying pkg/__init__module.so
# trying pkg/__init__.py
import pkg # from pkg/__init__.py
# wrote pkg/__init__.pyc
# trying pkg/test_ext.i386-linux-gnu.so
# trying pkg/test_ext.so
# trying pkg/test_extmodule.so
# trying pkg/test_ext.py
# trying pkg/test_ext.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named test_ext
```

One can see that the `pkg` package was found relative to my current working directory, but it did not locate a `test_ext` module after trying various extensions.

Comment: The -vv option to python is incredible useful for tracking down import issues. My problem is solved.